# Sharepoint 2013 Custom List PreSaveAction()

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a list with 2 columns
column1 (number)
column2 (number)

I am trying to validate the form before saving with PreSaveAction()

column1 has to be greater than column2

I am inserting the following code in a script editor web part on NewForm.aspx, the return false alert is firing in every case. Any obvious reason for this?

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function()
  {
    var column1 = $("input[value='column1']").attr("title");
    var column2 = $("input[value='column2']").attr("title");
  });

  function PreSaveAction()
  {
    if (column1 <= column2)
    {
      alert("column1 has to be greater than column2");
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: your jQuery selector is invalid, you need to search by id and get control value, something like this `$("input[id*=column1]").val()`

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<script language="javascript">
var column1=0;
var column2=0;
$(function()
  {
    column1 = $("input[value='column1']").attr("title");
    column2 = $("input[value='column2']").attr("title");
  });

  function PreSaveAction()
  {
    if (column1 <= column2)
    {
      alert("column1 has to be greater than column2");
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
      }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you need to change your jQuery selector.
2. You are trying to set value of `column1` and `column2` variable on document.ready(i.e. $(function()). Instead you can assign these values in `PreSaveAction` function only.

**Refer below code. I have made above changes. This code should work for you.**

```
<script language="javascript">

    function PreSaveAction() {
        var column1 = $("input[title='column1']").val();
        var column2 = $("input[title='column2']").val();

        if (column1 <= column2) {
            alert("column1 has to be greater than column2");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```